# Tikz: center a multiline text in a node without taking into account the subscript

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I would like to center a text in a tikz node without taking into account the subscripts/superscripts. When the text is a one line sentence, I can use `text depth=0` and `text height=1.5ex`. However, when the node contains a multiline text, then the text is not centered anymore.

Do you know any general solution to center any text without taking into account the subscripts/superscripts? And if not, at least do you have a way to use the current `text depth/height` solution on one line text, and the same style without `text depth/text height` for multiline nodes?

Examples:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
What i have:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    mynode/.style={
      circle,
      draw=blue,
      fill=blue!30,
      minimum width=2cm,
      % anchor=mid,
      text depth=0ex,
      text height=1.5ex,
      % align=center,
      % text width=1.5cm
    }
    ]
  \foreach \x [count=\i] in {$ABC_\gamma$,$ABC^\delta$,$ABC$,Two lines text}{
    \node[mynode] at (0,-3*\i) (c-\i) {\x};
    \node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=1pt] at (c-\i){};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
What I want:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[
    circle,
    draw=blue,
    fill=blue!30,
    minimum width=2cm,
    anchor=mid,
    align=center,
    text width=1.5cm
    ]{Two lines text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
What I do not want:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[
    circle,
    draw=blue,
    fill=blue!30,
    minimum width=2cm,
    anchor=mid,
    align=center,
    text width=1.5cm
    ]{$ABC_\gamma$};
  \node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=1pt] at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can `\smash` or in general use node `label`s

Comment: @percusse : `\smash` does not work for multiline nodes, no I need to manually choose if I want a multiline node or not, and it's quite annoying... And I can't find what option I should use to make `label`s work, because for me the problem is exactly the same...

Comment: @percusse as explained below, if I use `\smash` for all the single words, it works great, even if this method needs to manually modify the input text. But I'm not sure to see how `label` could be used as a replacement for `\smash` so if you can expand on it it would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long for a comment. I think your response to @percusse is misleading. According to what I find, `\smash` does work. Here I show three samples, first without subscript, then with subscript and smash and finally without smash. The difference from your upper pictures is due to your settings but *not* because of the subscript.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\begin{document}
What i have:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    mynode/.style={
      circle,
      draw=blue,
      fill=blue!30,
      minimum width=2cm,
      % anchor=mid,
      text depth=0ex,
      text height=1.5ex,
      % align=center,
      % text width=1.5cm
    }
    ]
  \foreach \x [count=\i] in {$ABC_\gamma$,$ABC^\delta$,$ABC$,Two lines text}{
    \node[mynode] at (3*\i,0) (c-\i) {\x};
    \node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=1pt] at (c-\i){};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\\
% What I want:\\
% \begin{tikzpicture}
%   \node[
%     circle,
%     draw=blue,
%     fill=blue!30,
%     minimum width=2cm,
%     anchor=mid,
%     align=center,
%     text width=1.5cm
%     ]{Two lines text};
% \end{tikzpicture}
% \\
What I do not want:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[
    circle,
    draw=blue,
    fill=blue!30,
    minimum width=2cm,
    anchor=mid,
    align=center,
    text width=1.5cm
    ]{$ABC$};
  \node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=1pt](c5) at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[
    circle,
    draw=blue,
    fill=blue!30,
    minimum width=2cm,
    anchor=mid,
    align=center,
    text width=1.5cm
    ]{$AB\smash{C_{\gamma}}$};
  \node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=1pt](c6) at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
  \node[
    circle,
    draw=blue,
    fill=blue!30,
    minimum width=2cm,
    anchor=mid,
    align=center,
    text width=1.5cm
    ]{$ABC_{\gamma}$};
  \node[circle,fill=red,inner sep=1pt](c7) at (0,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[blue] (c5-| current page text area.west) --
(c6-| current page text area.east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was using `\smash` on the whole text, and because of that is was not working. But indeed if I specify it "word by word" it works great (even if the solution still need a manual modification of the input text, it's better than nothing). Thank you! And I'm curious, if you know a way to do that without changing the input text at all, let me know !

Comment: @tobiasBora I am sorry, I can't offer a perfect solution. I have been playing around with `\strut` and so on, but there will be always something ugly or that might break. I'd be really interested to see what `@percusse meant by `label`s.